# SwiftUI custom Annotation map with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, uiviewrepresentable

***First of all before posting here I have read the StackOverflow rules for posting, anyway if I have done something wrong please comment it to edit the post.***

Good morning || afternoon || evening, I have a question that I've been struggling with for a few weeks, and that is that I'm trying to create a customView with SwiftUI for the map annotations.
The map view is created with UIViewRepresentable so I can update the annotations.

**UIViewRepresentable (Mapita):**

```
struct Mapita: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var gasAnnotations: [GasStationAnnotation]
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        mapView.region = region
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        mapView.addAnnotations(gasAnnotations) // [MKAnnotation]
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapitaCoordinator {
        MapitaCoordinator(self)
    }
    
    class MapitaCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: Mapita
        
        init(_ parent: Mapita) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
            parent.region = mapView.region
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            if let customAnnotation = annotation as? GasStationAnnotation {
                let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: customAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "GasStationAnnotation")
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true

                let customView = GasStationAnnotationView(backgroundColor: .white,
                                                          gasStationImage: customAnnotation.companyImage,
                                                          idStation: customAnnotation.gasStationID,
                                                          gasStationAnnotation: customAnnotation)
                let uiView = UIHostingController(rootView: customView).view
                annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = uiView

                return annotationView
            } else {
                return nil
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the MKMapViewDelegate function:

`func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

**(GasStationAnnotation has inheritance from MKAnnotation and NSObject)**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
     if let customAnnotation = annotation as? GasStationAnnotation {
                let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: customAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "GasStationAnnotation")
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true

                let customView = GasStationAnnotationView(backgroundColor: .white,
                                                          gasStationImage: customAnnotation.companyImage,
                                                          idStation: customAnnotation.gasStationID,
                                                          gasStationAnnotation: customAnnotation)
                let uiView = UIHostingController(rootView: customView).view
                annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = uiView

                return annotationView
            } else {
                return nil
            }

        }
```

**GasStationAnnotationView** is my custom view (SwiftUI) of the annotation I want to paint on the map but it doesn't work.

```
import SwiftUI

struct GasStationAnnotationView: View {
    
    @State var gasStationButtonTapped: Bool = false
    @State var backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
    @State var gasStationImage: String = "other"
    @State var widthSize: CGFloat = .zero
    @State var idStation: Int = .zero
    @State var gasStationAnnotation: GasStationAnnotation? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: .zero) {
            HStack(spacing: .zero) {
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.dotTwo))) {
                        gasStationButtonTapped.toggle()
                        widthSize = gasStationButtonTapped ? CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.fifty) : .zero
                    }
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Image(gasStationImage)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.thirty),
                                   height: CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.thirty))
                            .cornerRadius(CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.thirtySix))
                    }
                }
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding(CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.two))
                .background(Color(backgroundColor))
                .cornerRadius(CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.thirtySix))
                
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("info")
                }
                .frame(width: self.widthSize, height: CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.twenty))
            }
            .background(Color(backgroundColor))
            .cornerRadius(CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.thirtySix))
            
            Image(systemName: "triangle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundColor(Color(backgroundColor))
                .frame(width: CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.five), height: CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.ten))
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.hundredEighty)))
                .offset(y: -CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.floatThreeDotFive))
                .padding(.bottom, CGFloat(Constants.DefaultValues.twenty))
        }
    }
}

struct GasStationAnnotationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GasStationAnnotationView()
    }
}
```

I am trying to display a custom view to replace the default annotations that the MKMapView object has using SwiftUI,
I have tried to use UIHostingController without success.

Comment: Well, at the end of all i solved by my self, with a simple line of code hehe

Answer (score 0):

So at the end of all i solved by myself, hehe, anyway if someone have same problem as me with updating the annotations on the map by the location or dragging the map here is the solution for SwiftUI object/view Map:

```
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel
    @State var selectedStation: Int?
    @State var id = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: viewModel.gasStationAnnotations) { annotation in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: annotation.coordinateY, longitude: annotation.coordinateX)) {
                    GasStationAnnotationView(gasStationAnnotation: annotation, selectedStation: $selectedStation)
                }
            }
            .id(id)
            .onChange(of: viewModel.gasStationAnnotations) { _ in
                id = UUID()
            }
}
```

The solution is to add an universal unique identifier (UUID) to my view, to force SwiftUI to instantiate the Map view each time the array of annotations changes in the viewModel, and add it to the Map object/view as a function .id(id)

**Some warnings**
Please take care with this function .id(UUID) because in some cases  if you use too many unique identifiers are added to views, it could cause an increase in memory usage and a negative impact on performance. Therefore, it is important to use the .id() function effectively and only where necessary.